# Issues with custom font in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, uilabel, uifont, custom-font

I followed the steps outlined in various locations using the `UIAppFonts` property list key. I'm using the Aller Light font. I've added it as a resource, added the font name correctly in the info property list, and am now attempting to use it, however every attempt to do so results in the default font being displayed. So far I've tried:

```
[leader setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Aller Light" size:20.0]];
[leader setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AllerLight" size:20.0]];
[leader setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Aller-Light" size:20.0]];
[leader setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Aller-Lt.ttf" size:20.0]];

leader.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Aller Light" size:20.0];
... with all the variants listed above
```

None of them work. Running `NSLog(@"Available fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);` returns:

```
Available fonts: (
    ...
    "Aller Light",
    ...
)
```

Thoughts or solutions? Installing the font on my mac and looking in Font Book, the name of the font is Aller Light. Verifying the font in Font Book indicates that the font name is in fact simply Aller Light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List all fonts

```
for (NSString *name in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"Family name : %@", name);
    for (NSString *font in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:name]) {
        NSLog(@"Font name : %@", font);             
    }
}
```