# Custom font not showing on device, but does on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uifont, custom-font

I've been playing around with custom fonts in iOS and have got most of it figured out apart from the custom font won't show on any of my devices.

1. I have added the font to the root of the project file.
2. Added it to the info.plist file under the array or "Fonts provided by application"
3. Checked that the case sensitivity of both the original file and what I added to the info.plist file are the same.
4. Used `[playMenuBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname" size:40]];` to make the font work.

When I run my app in the Simulator it all appears fine and works. However as soon as I run it on a physical device, it displays the default font with the default size.

If I use:
`UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"VINCASTENCIL" size:20];
NSLog(@"Font:%@", font);`

Then the simulator returns:
`2012-04-07 01:10:41.544 AppName[47412:f803] Font:<UICFFont: 0x683e040> font-family: "VINCA STENCIL"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 20px`

Where as the device returns:
`2012-04-07 00:42:56.358 AppName[5079:707] Font:(null)`

I have tried everything, including trying all the names that FontBook tells me the font could be named. I know it's free and there isn't a licence on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it's driving me nuts and I really don't want to use images for al of these as localisation would then be a pain!

Comment: Is the font being packaged with the iOS app?

Comment: Does `[UIFont familyNames]` list the font you added?

Comment: what extensions have font files? TTF or ttf?

Comment: @TheDeveloper I have dragged the font into the project manager in Xcode and it appears in my resources list. Is that what you mean by packed?

Comment: @MrMage I tried adding:  
`NSArray *fontArray = [UIFont familyNames];  
NSLog(@"Font FamilyNames:%@", fontArray);`
And on the simulator my font appears in the list, where as again on the device it does not.

Comment: @NeverBe It is a .ttf file extension and I've made sure it's the same case everywhere. I have also tried changing it to uppercase everywhere just to check, and it made no difference.

Comment: did you try clean build and delete app from device?

Comment: @NeverBe Yep, tried that. Still no joy. :-(

Comment: list all fonts like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750222/issues-with-custom-font-in-ios/9750315#9750315

Comment: Posted the answer below and all works now. Thanks for you help everyone.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Right, I've just managed to get this working. Everything I was doing was correct but for some reason it wasn't adding my font file to 'Targets' -> 'Build Phases' -> 'Copy Bundle Resources'. By manually adding it to this list, the font then shows on the device.

This is the second time this project has not added a file here automatically (it's done it previously with a class I added, and it didn't) so I think it's something wrong with my project, or a bug in Xcode.

Thanks to everyone for your suggestions and help. :-D

Comment: This is sort of what I sad D:

Comment: @TheDeveloper yeah was the reason I checked it in the end. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Seems like xcode doesn't add TTF files to the bundle resources by default, unlike eg png's. Same problem here,

Comment: I'm also facing same problem but fonts are showing in Copy Bundle Resources.i Added two custom fonts. One font is working but the second one is not working ... i dunno why

Comment: @OMerObaid I found double checking the name it's called useful as well. Best way to see if your device knows a font is there is looping through `[UIFont familyNames]` and `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:]` and log out the font names. FontBook is also really great for seeing what a font should be named.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, follow all the directions mentioned above and you should be fine. Something else to look out for: case sensitivity. In your *.plist file and `Fonts provided by application`. The simulator might ignore capitalization, but the device will not. For example, 'Facebook' is not the same as 'FaceBook'. (This led to the font working in the simulator, but not the device!)