# UIFont custom font not displaying on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

I have a problem with custom font. Namely it's Tw Cen MT.ttf

It's the same problem as in here:
[Custom font not showing on device, but does on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050613/custom-font-not-showing-on-device-but-does-on-simulator)

Except the given solution doesn't work for me.

I have done exactly what you should do:

1. Added Font to Info.plist
2. Added Font to Copy Bundle Resources section in Build Phases.
3. Used font programmatically by name not filename.

It still doesn't work. What's more interesting - when I list available fonts:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont familyNames]);
```

It shows me my font on simulator but does not show it on the device. I tested it both on the new iPad and iPhone 4 with iOS 6.

Any advice?

Comment: You should make sure you aren't having the same problem as in that other question by opening up the .app bundle and checking for the font. Or `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ofType:]` in the app. Nothing like knowing for sure that the file is there.

Comment: It gives me paths both in simulator and device enviroment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure not to confuse the family name with the font name. This is the code I use to check the real name of my fonts.-

```
NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];
for (NSString *aFamilyName in familyNames) {
     NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:aFamilyName];
     for (NSString *aFontName in fontNames) {
        NSLog(@"%@", aFontName);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - it turn's out I had wrong name - it's correct name is TwCenMT-Regular. Still - It's listed when I test on simulator and disappears when running on device.

Comment: Ok - you were right with other family name, but I misspelled it while correcting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you got the name of the font right. The simulator is not case sensitive whereas the phone is.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure it's right. I know that problem from loading images by name :)