# Font Changes On running app

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, interface, xcode6.3

I am making a Profit and loss calculator.
I assigned a custom font to text field and ran the app in the simulator.
when the app ran it for no reason changed the font.

Here are the images:

While building the interface
 [image: While building the interface]

And When i run the app, Font Changed!

[image: And When i run the app, Font Changed!]

What should I do?

Comment: Did you add the fonts to the bundle?

Comment: Yes, I did add fonts to the bundle.

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050613/custom-font-not-showing-on-device-but-does-on-simulator

Comment: What Did You Buy? - looks correct, maybe something wrong at your code or looks like when the text is not feet, font options other.

Comment: Yeah something is really strange!

Comment: updating Xcode right now, might be a bug.

Comment: Updated but the problem is still there. Probably a bug or something. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Create @property for each object and then set the font for each label/textfield in viewDidLoad.