# UITableView Section Header Font Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, interface-builder, uifont

I'm trying to customize the section header for a UITableView. The UITableView was created in IB. I'm having 2 issues that I cannot figure out.

1. The font size will not increase past about 18 or something regardless of how large the UILabel is.
2. The section headers are obscuring the tables.

I've colored the labels blue so you can see their size.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Name of section
NSString *header = [[purchases allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];

// Label for section header
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 230, 45);
label.textColor = _orange;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC Medium" size:52];
label.text = header;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

// View to contain label
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 230, 45)];
[view autorelease];
[view addSubview:label];

return view;
}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: 1. Font may be don't exist with this name. 2. You should use all cell width for header view, also did you define delegate for header height?

Comment: Font exists (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5484). Good call on the header height protocol. I'll try that now.

Comment: Your font named as STHeitiTC-Medium. Font list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750222/issues-with-custom-font-in-ios/9750315#9750315

Comment: Oh thanks. I wish that information was easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should add table view delegate method for header height
2. You should use all cell width for header view.
3. Your font named as STHeitiTC-Medium